# Automated FIAT Transfer to bank from Exchange

Tags: automation, fiat

is it possible to trigger an automated wire to a bank account with an exchange platform?

we do want to make a couple of transactions a day depending on the bitcoin trading price based on rule sets.

from our wallet --> send to exchange --> automated process to sell into EUR --> wire send to Bank

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This would vary widely by exchange. The BTC transfer and trade can almost definitely be automated through most large exchange's APIs. Fiat withdrawals might be possible, but I don't recall seeing any APIs for that recently. Your best bet would be to contact the exchanges and ask about it, as I suspect it is a feature that is available "on-demand" for larger clients, and they might be willing to support you on it.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitstamp provide API](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/) for both auto selling (it's called "liquidation address") and withdrawals. Other exchanges may provide similar features.